# get facebook page full public photostream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, screen-scraping, mechanize-python

there's only one similar question and it's not been answered. not for me at least.
There are public pages on Facebook, suppose i want to get their photostream ? their album pictures ?
I don't see how the Graph API allows me access since i can't get an access token, if i browse from my browser, NOT LOGGED IN, i can still see this public information, so how do i use the AI to access it.

BTW, i tried scrapping with python+mechanize and it's no go as if u get the regular we photo stream u get only partial, no all of it and the rest you need to scroll or to know how to build the same request the browser is building, but suprise suprise the JS doing the request is obfuscated pretty well...

Any help  ?

Comment: You might like looking into FQL, it might have something you would like to use, example `select src from photo where owner=uid`

Comment: 1. can i use FQL in python ? as far as i know i can do that only with JS
2. doesn't FQL much like the API need auth_token which requires me to login ?

Comment: 1.Yes, you can. Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/third-party-sdks/#python).   2. Yes it requires access token but you can easily use App Access token to access public data.

Comment: 10x, but App Access is for your FB application to access the API, i don't have any nor i want one, i want to get some images and text based on data i would like to collect from public pages (simpsons, family guy public pages etc...). That i was unable to find, you say i need to get an application  id for non exciting application just so i can do this script ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any hands on with python. I just thought this might help you a bit. I mean the API route.

Comment: it's a nice idea, i see now that facebook in the last week or so blocked anonymous access to public pages, though some old pages still give that access if you try to brose pictures for example you can see the first ones, and the rest not, the loading will stay forever and XHR shows you have HTTP 500, probably because of no AUTH. So maybe the API this way are the way to go...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in short it's not possible to do what i wanted annonymously, moreover at the moment, only some of the API works in the web site by accident only, if u are not logged in FB do not want to let u see any page and anyone, considering the last article about their cooperation with the US gov. it's not surprising.

In any case i just use grease money and FF to get a full page\album and then download the whole thing and i i need scrapping i'll do it on those pages with a script.
basically if i log in i can get a full page using the scripts in script monkey.... though script monkey is easier since he has the browser to parse all the data and works inside the browser...

I gave up after 3 weeks...

Comment: Denying scraping pages has nothing to do with the current state of affairs of US government. The API is not a reflection of public browser presentation it's a way to obtain Facebook data based on the API definition. Just because it's public in your browser doesn't mean the API will offer it. Also if all you are doing is downloading photos clicking a button to create an application is minimal, you aren't pushing it to production so it can remain solely for your usage. Finally, public photos on pages without age/country restrictions should be accessible without an access token e.g. `/boo/photos`